# Javascript Cookies - Can they be accessed by a server side scripting language, visa versa?

Tags: javascript, cookies, server-side

I am learning **Javascript** and have been a back-end Web Developer for 25 years. MY question is quite simple; can you access a **cookie** set by **Javascript** with a **server side scripting language**, such as **PHP**, visa versa?

Thank you,

Comment: Yes you can. Cookies are always set in the client's browser. They are transmitted to the back-end by cookies https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers-cookie/#:~:text=A%20cookie%20is%20an%20HTTP,It%20is%20an%20optional%20header.
PHP does that automatically for you when you set cookies.

Comment: As far as i know cookies are not specific to a programming language. You can read and write from both. Though `HttpOnly` cookies [aren't readable by JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies) to try and mitigate XSS attacks

Comment: @thcp cookies may also be set by the server as part of an HTTP response.

Comment: @Pointy not true. A server can send a header to ask client's to set a cookie. It the client chose not to set this cookie, the cookie won't be set. It's not the server that set the cookie, it only send a request to set a cookie

Comment: @mmeisson well fine, that's accurate, but most clients are pretty cooperative :)

Comment: Except when clients are "server side scripts" I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Cookies are data managed by browser, and transmitted on each requests.

Cookies are sent by browsers via http requests, any script / programm can read them server side.

Remember that cookies are linked to domains, and that you can only access to cookies linked to your page domain.

You may want to read :
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: That's what I figured. Since they are stored in the browser (non httponly), I just wanted to make sure. Does Javascript have a way to encrypt the cookies with a hash algorithm? I also heard that tokens aren't the most secure way to encrypt cookies?

Comment: From what I just read, cookies are set on the client side only. So, it makes sense that any language that has access to the HTTP client can read and write.  Since the day when we first visit a site and the site needs to notify the visitor of their use of cookies, they probably just set a cookie that says, "acceptCookie, true" Something like that.